# What is the best way to store secure user data in php sessions?

Tags: php

I'm coding a private message system in `PHP` for secure encrypted communications.

Every time a user registers an account, I'll create a new RSA private key using `phpseclib` and will encrypt it in `AES` using the user's password, which will be securely stored hashed and salted in the database.

Every time a user logs in with his password, he should also unlock his private key and maintain it on the fly.

This script is obviously intended to run only under SSL connections.

The problem is that I need to maintain a non-encrypted version of the private key in the user's session to make sure he is able to read every message and write new messages without inserting the password on every page refresh.

Storing in the PHP Session is not a secure solution since the PHP Sessions are still stored on the server and can be compromised.

Storing it in a Cookie is not a good solution since a Cookie can be easily stolen (but in this way I put the destiny of the user in his own hands).

Is it possibile with ajax to maintain the key in a PHP variable (not Session) and never refresh the page but getting and writing messages using ajax? or is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where will the RSA keys be stored? If they are stored on the server then what is the point of encrypting when the keys can be stolen as well?

Comment: Your only option in PHP is to use sessions. Now you don't have to store sessions on the disk as you can use memcached or custom session handler to store the data elsewhere, but unless you want to decrypt the key on every request you need to temporarily store the key somewhere. This whole idea feels a bit overkill to me.

Comment: So, basically, you want to (1) generate a per-user encryption keypair upon registration, (2) maintain both the public and private keys for the user on the server, and (3) transmit the private key to the user when they log in, so that (4) you can transmit their encrypted messages to the browser and (5) decrypt them so that only that user on that browser can see the messages? Hint: SSL already handles the server<->browser encryption for you. Store your messages encrypted on the server, decrypt them on the server (in-memory) and return the result via HTTPS to the user.

Comment: "Storing in the PHP Session is not a secure solution since the PHP Sessions are still stored on the server and can be compromised." - If your server is compromised (i.e. somebody can access the sessions along with anything else) then all bets are off. Why you use the time saved by not implementing such a complicated system and ensuring that your server is secure. i.e. do a security audit. This seems a more worthwhile exercise.

Comment: @granpasso - Lets get this straight. You do not have faith in the security of your server but you are prepared to trust and Tom Dick or Harry at the client end to be secure in their dealings with your server? Is that correct. My what a topsy turvy world you live in.

Comment: Why not encrypt and decrypt the mesasages on the clients? So your users maintain full control over their keys and the plain messages are never accessible on your server. Everything else seems like half-assed security with no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have full control and can limit access/visibility to your database, you can switch over storing your session data from file storage to using database as session store.  This assumes of course your db is secure enough for your needs.   You can check out a detailed overview on how to setup php for storing session to your database here: http://www.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_MySQL-based_sessions

Assuming you don't need to preserve session data across a database restart, you could also make the session store table's storage engine to be `MEMORY` instead of Innodb or MyISAM.  This will make it pretty snappy and avoid the concern you might have of session data being inside the db files on disk in an unencrypted state.

Comment: @granpasso - The server administrator has the root password (or the moral equivalent in windows) and therefore is able to access anything. The only exception is to have things encrypted and you will have to type in a password upon reboot. This is not practical as you might be ill/on holiday/sleeping...

Answer (score 0):

If you store the private key anywhere on the server, then it's only as safe as your trust in anyone who has root access to that server.  For a secure messaging system, not all your users may want to trust the people who can access root.  (Do they?)  That suggests you'd want to store the private key on the user's machine.  As you suggested, doing that is a whole different set of security questions.

I'm assuming your users are using web browsers to access your system, since you mentioned cookies.  Most web browsers also support the idea of local storage (non-cookie), which *might* be an option to investigate; I'm not expert at all in that area so won't comment further.

Security is hard, and complex.  Be wary of any simple answers, and be aware that no security is perfect.  Good luck.